# Difftime giving a larger than expected value

Tags: c, time

When I print the result of difftime, I get the result: -4334284568731237.000000.  Why is this?

```
    //time1 and time2 are both of type time_t

    time_t temp;

    char val[] = "06:02";
    struct tm tm;
    strptime(val, "%H:%M", &tm);
    temp = mktime(&tm);
    items[0].time1 = temp;

    char val2[] = "06:43";
    struct tm tm;
    strptime(val2, "%H:%M", &tm);
    temp = mktime(&tm);
    items[0].time2 = temp;

    printf("%f\n", difftime(items[0].time1, items[0].time2));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assuming `tm` variables are declared at block scope with automatic storage duration.

> Why is this?

You only set the hour and minutes:

```
struct tm tm;                  // uninitialized
strptime(val2, "%H:%M", &tm);  // sets only tm.tm_hour and tm.tm_min
```

`strptime` doesn't initialize `tm`, only stores what it reads. The rest of members of `struct tm` are uninitialized, so they have "indeterminate" values - any values. So it may just happen that the first `tm` has different value of a year from the other `tm`, which results in a big difference in what `mktime` returns when it parses `tm`.

From the `strptime` man page: `tm should be initialized before the call`. So do initialize the structure before calling `strptime`:

```
struct tm tm = {0};
strptime(val2, "%H:%M", &tm);
```